# VS2012 Debugger Not Hitting breakpoints

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, solution-package

I've got the FBA2013 pack installed and working beautifully on our SP2013 farm. I'm adding some custom fields to gather more user information, but I cannot get VS2012 to hit any breakpoints I set. The steps I've been using are as follows:

- Rebuild the WSP solution
- Undeploy old/redeploy new
- Activate all features
- Attach to the correct w3wp process with VS2012

I know that I have attached to the correct process, because my breakpoints appear solid red. If I attach to the "wrong" w3wp I get the typical "Breakpoint will not be hit...". Alas, even though it appears I am successfully attached, all of my breakpoints are blown right by, making debugging a serious chore/mystery. Anyone have any clue what may be going on here?

Comment: Have you restarted the SharePoint timerjob and performed the IISReset manually as well?

Comment: I perform an IISReset every time the solution is deployed. I haven't tried restarting the SharePoint Timer service after deployment.

Comment: Nope, same story. I've gotten along so far by simply writing to the event log lol definitely not ideal.

Comment: So it's quite lame to ask if you're using debug build instead of release?

Comment: Not at all, though unfortunately I am building in debug mode.

Comment: Write `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in the place where you want to attach debugger and see if that helpd? Also make sure that you're attaching to the w3p.exe process which is being run by application pool account of web application.

Answer (score 1):

could be a couple of reasons why its not hitting!! the first thing is that its loading the dll otherwise it wouldnt be a solid break point. The next part is how are you attaching to the dll?

when you go to attach are you first using the debug (by your comment you are)and not release, when you get the list of dll's within **Attach To** click on the button **select** to select from a list of types, uncheck all appart from managed (v2.0 , v1.1, v1.0) only and click ok... now attach to the w3wp.exe (just incase select all w3wp.exe to attach to) if there is more than one. If that doesnt work do the same again this time uncheck all and check managed (v4.0) only and click ok, now attach to w3wp.exe

make sure you put your first break point at the start(entry point) for the code! maybe its not hitting because its not getting to that code?

as your debugging try to refresh app pool in iis, I remember doing this for 2007 when i had the same issue, after refreshing app pool accounts that w3wp.exe resides in, I reload page and attach to process (attach whilst page is loading) it then debugs properly :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have similar issues where I wouldn't hit break points if I didn't let the site compile first prior to attempting to attach to the process.

Build then deploy
Add solution
Activate all features
Hit the site to load it
Open process list and attach to process
Debug (hopefully)